# Usings filtering with "WHERE" clause in Data Studio SQL datasource to reference a function

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

Please how can I reference a filter function in Data Studio from my SQL Query Data Source? For example

select * from [table] where date between ["Date Range Control" function]

Comment: **Needs details [REVISION 1]**: Provide a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report [TO-DO] and sample data set(s) / shared Google Sheet [TO-DO] of the scenario, that shows 1) Input table(s) (~9 rows) / chart in both Question [TO-DO] and Report [TO-DO] 2) Expected table / charts in both Question [TO-DO] & Report [TO-DO] 3) Issue / attempt at solving in both Question [TO-DO] & Report [TO-DO]. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to visualise and pinpoint a suggestion to a specific use case

Answer (score 1):

If you edit your data source, you'll see a tickbox to enable date range parameters. Once ticked you can refer to the two new data range parameters it creates in your custom query. These two new parameters will be called:
DS_START_DATE
DS_END_DATE